# Does this stem have a washer that I can replace?

Tags: sink, bathroom-fixtures

My bathroom sink cold water faucet was leaking into the cabinet ([related post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/237239/how-to-get-at-the-washer-inside-this-bathroom-sink-faucet/237244#237244)).

I took apart the faucet stem to see if there was a washer I could change and I do not understand what I am looking at (see photo).

I do not see a washer.  What part of this do I change?  If it is the little black o-ring, how do I measure it to buy a new one?

[image: stem]

Comment: You must replace the entire cartridge. - Take your faucet make and model to a plumbing supply outlet and they will identify the replacement cartridge you need. - They often come in packs of two, and plumbers recommend replacing both hot and cold; if one is worn out the other will surely fail soon.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri If that is so, I might as well buy a whole new faucet set. Oh well.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC  Those cartridges usually cost about $9 bucks a piece.  That will be cheaper than a new faucet and faster to install than a new faucet.

Comment: include a picture of the left end of the cylinder

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri make that an answer!

Comment: @JACK a new faucet set is less than twice the cost of 2 replacement cylinders and can be easily ordered online (saving a trip to the plumbing supply store), and the current faucet and all connectors are old.  The new look is worth the little added price.  I hope the installation is easy (or I'll be back here asking for help).

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC  We'll be here... good luck.

Comment: Just in case this is what's driving the cost, you don't have to use brand-name parts! When I replaced my faucet cartridges I bought a set from Danco labled "for Delta faucets." It cost about $5 at Home Depot. I brought one of the old cartridges into the store to match it.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I think the idea of replacing semi-expensive cartridges is aimed at me. 
 Replacing the entire faucet can be quite an adventure, depending upon how confined the space is underneath and how physically agile is the person doing the replacement.  The older I get, the more I'm willing to spend to not be under the sink.  Give me a few more years and I'll gladly pay more than the faucet is worth to not be under the sink.

Comment: @WayneConrad isn't that what you have kids for? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace the entire cartridge.

Take your faucet make and model to a plumbing supply outlet and they will identify the replacement cartridge you need. Take the old cartridge too, since you've already removed it.

They often come in packs of two, and plumbers recommend replacing both hot and cold. If one is worn out the other will surely fail soon.